# Netsuite suitelet to refresh current page

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have Netsuite suitelet that is deployed on item fulfillment to update a custom field once the button is clicked. It is working fine. The response.write opens a new tab in the browser window and displays the desired message, all good.

However I want the current item fulfillment page to be refreshed before opening the new tab to display the message. Is that possible?
thank you

I tried but did not find a command to refresh current page in a server script (suitelet)

Comment: can you show the scripts that you have?

Comment: please share the script code and we might be able to guide you.

Comment: You will likely need to use client-side JavaScript script for this. Possibly something like `window.opener.location.reload()` on the Suitelet after the page is loaded. This is assuming I understand what you're trying to accomplish. It's difficult without seeing your code.